# Moodle Language synchronisation

Tags: php, curl, moodle

Hi I recently got used to moodle http://moodle.org.
I want to use the official Moodle App for IOs/Android.
However I want the language to be german when using the app.
Here is an example screenshot:
[image: moodleapp]

The docs say that I have to upload a mobile.php to my lang/en folder in order to customize the language of the app. See http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Mobile_app#Translation (applies for newer versions as well). The file is structured like this
    http://pastebin.com/5TJWZ4ue

However if I upload this file to my server, the app does not change it's language. It is still english.

I hope that someone with more insight to moodle can help me.

Comment: "wstoken= 33d8e706d7c230b83eb265b4efbcea62". Extra space?

Comment: if i change the extra space the error message changes but is not as specific as i'd like it to be.
See my edit

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do? what do you mean change the language?

Comment: Basically I am trying to customize the mooodle mobile app by setting up language and css files on the server side. This is explained in http://docs.moodle.org/25/de/Mobile_App
The app seems to be english by default. Therefore I have copied a mobile.php to my lang/eng folder. 
But as stated above I get erros while syncing the language via app. Now I am trying to understand the problem by using curl to get a more detailed error description.

Comment: And what is the error msg? You can get more detailed error when you turn debugging on: http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Debugging#Debug_messages
Also, are you positively sure you purged the cache?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to install the German language pack :

*Settings > Site administration > Language > Language packs*

Then you can change the default language for the site to German :

*Administration > Site administration > Language > Language settings.*

also for individual user profiles :

*Administration > My profile settings > Edit profile.*

More information here
http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Language_settings

Comment: Changing/installing the language pack does not apply for the mobile app. As described in http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Mobile_app#Translation
i need to install a mobile.php which I have done.
I simply changed one keyword in the default mobile.php which is described here: http://jsfiddle.net/jleyva/9AFKN/2/embedded/result/
this however does not work...

Comment: As described, this answer did not work...
But Thanks for the work.

Answer (score 0):

For moodle mobile language customization, go to the mobile features section in the site admin. Scroll down to custom language strings. Update your strings there. It works